# Get Model List Json using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql in Asp.Net Core

Tags: mysql, list, asp.net-core, model, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

How to return `MenuList JSON string` using `Pomelo`? When i add a `MenuList` in my `Model` i will get an error showing me "Unknown Column MenuList". Because in my `MySql` Menus.tbl there is no `MenuList` column.

Any solution for me please, thanks in advance !

Menus.cs

```
public class Menus
{
    [Key]
    public int MenuId { set; get; }
    public string MenuName { set; get; }
    public int? ParentId { set; get; }
    public int ActiveNo { set; get; }
    public List<Menus> MenuList { set; get; }
}
```

MenusController.cs

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult<List<Menus>> GetMenus()
    {
        List<Menus> menuList = new List<Menus>();

        foreach (Menus m in _context.menusss.ToList())
        {
            menuList.Add(m);
        }

        List<Menus> menuTree = GetMenuTree(menuList, null);
        return menuTree;
    }

    private List<Menus> GetMenuTree(List<Menus> list, int? parentId)
    {
        return list.Where(x => x.ParentId == parentId).Select(x => new Menus()
        {
            MenuId = x.MenuId,
            MenuName = x.MenuName,
            ParentId = x.ParentId,
            ActiveNo = x.ActiveNo,
            MenuList = GetMenuTree(list, x.MenuId)
        }).ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I just tried your code, but fails to reproduce. I guess the reason is something related to `[NotMapped]`.  Could you please show us more details? Also,  if I understand correctly, you should use `List<Menus> MenuList` instead of `Menus MenuList`.

Comment: @itminus Please look at my MenusController.cs, im trying to get a JSON string like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, just add `[NotMapped]' to ignore the property.

```
public class Menus
{
    [Key]
    public int MenuId { set; get; }
    public string MenuName { set; get; }
    public int? ParentId { set; get; }
    public int ActiveNo { set; get; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<Menus> MenuList { set; get; }
}
```